# Malformed input around byte in Java while using DataInputStream

Tags: java, datainputstream

I have a code that takes inputstream and prints it. When I use `BufferedReader` the code prints the stream in console but when I use `DataInputStream` I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.UTFDataFormatException: malformed input around byte 6351
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:656)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

The code is as below:

```
public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Socket socket = new Socket("host", port);
            DataInputStream in       =  null;
    //        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            while(true){
    //            System.out.println(bufferedReader.readLine());
                System.out.println(in.readUTF());
            }
        }
    }
```

Also when I use `readLine()` with `DataInputStream`, `intellij` shows that it is deprecated. Finally I need to read the stream and pass it line by line to another method like this:

`line = in.readUTF();`

I get the same error. How can I rectify the error?

Comment: You're putting some constraint on the data in the inputStream by reading it via `readUTF()`. Apparently the data is not a valid UTF-8. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readUTF()
`If the first byte of a group matches the pattern 1111xxxx or the pattern 10xxxxxx, then a UTFDataFormatException is thrown.`

Comment: Ok. Got it. `stream` is basically bytes. I need to use some kind of `Reader` such as `BufferedReader` to read data.

Answer (score -3):

It probably a bit too late but here's an answer.
In the following code you shouldn't write:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("host", port);
```

The Socket expects an IP-Address not a name.
It should be for example:

```
Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.87", port);
```

Comment: This is not at all what he questioned.

Comment: I'm assuming the person that asked the question redacted the IP that they used